# Import ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a folder structure for project with small application and some additional scripts, which are not directly used by application (they are used for some data science on data in `data` folder):

```
project
   data
   doc    
   src
   └───scripts1
           script1_1.py
           script1_2.py
       scripts2
           script2_1.py
       application
           common
               __init__.py   
               config.py
           enrichment
               __init__.py
                module1.py
                module2.py
           __init__.py
           app.py
```

Script `app.py` **is always entry point** and is used for starting the application. I want to be able to use relative imports in this folder structure. For example I want to import `Configuration` class, which is located in `config.py` inside of `module1.py`. But when I run `app.py` and have this import statement in `module1.py`:

`from ..common.config import Configuration`

I get the following error:

```
  File ".../project/src/application/enrichment/module1.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..common.config import Configuration
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I would also need to import enrichment modules in `app.py`, guess it should work similarly:

```
from .enrichment.module1 import <func or class>
```

I have read multiple threads on module importing, but I am still not able to reconstruct the behavior, where I am able to use these relative imports and not get the ValueError. In one older project I used path importing in __init__.py files, but I hope it can be solved somehow better, because it was a bit magic for me. Really thanks for any help.

Comment: What script are you running when you are getting this error?

Comment: I am running app.py. My bad I did not mention it, I will add it to to the question.

Comment: Well. I moved app.py one directory layer up (to src folder) as it is suggested in your tutorial and now it works. Thank you. But still, is there any way, how could be this functionality achieved without moving the app.py? To preserve the directory structure as it is in question.